# Trigger github action when a pull request is approved by a CODEOWNER

Tags: github, github-actions

Is there a way to trigger a pull request in Github when it gets approved by a CODEOWNER and only by a CODEOWNER?

On https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#pull_request_review there's an example:

```
on:
  pull_request_review:
    types: [submitted]

jobs:
  approved:
    if: github.event.review.state == 'approved'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - run: echo "This PR was approved"
```

but I don't know how to limit it to code owners only.

Comment: There are some actions on the [Github Marketplace](https://github.com/marketplace?page=1&q=codeowner&query=codeowner+&type=actions) extracting Codeowners information. In your case you would probably need a `setup` job using a step to extract the reviewer login (username) from the event context, and check if this user belongs to the repository CODEOWNERS list (this information may probably be obtained from an action in the Marketplace). You would then set an output from the setup job and use it in the condition of your `approved` job: `if: [...] && ${{needs.setup.outputs.codeowner}} == 'true'`

Comment: I guess you don't need to put any condition in the workflow if you're using **CODEOWNERS** file for PR review. Ref. [CODEOWNER pull requests](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/22479) [Example of a CODEOWNERS file](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/managing-your-repositorys-settings-and-features/customizing-your-repository/about-code-owners#example-of-a-codeowners-file)

Comment: @Haridarshan I'm not sure I follow. I look at those links and they don't seem to have the answer. Even when you require a CODEOWNER review to merge, anyone can do a PR review, and I need my workflow to run only when the review is from a CODEOWNER, not others.